# Adding rows to data table using for loop

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I have a data table and I want to add rows to it using for loop but when I am doing that the loop stuck and it doesn't work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() == "")
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
                newRow[1] = "data";
                dt.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, i);
            }

        }
```

Comment: If this continually increases the row count, wouldn't this be an infinite loop?

Comment: yes but  I am adding rows only if a specific cell is blank. so how can i solve this?

Comment: `InsertAt` does not replace the row at `i` it adds a new one there.  Why not just `dt.Rows[i] = newRow;`?  Or really just `dt.Rows[i][1] = "data";` unless you want the other rows to be changed to the default values.

Comment: If you have a row with an empty cell, your code will create a new row and insert it before the row at `i`.  The row count increments, and the same row with the blank cell is now at `i+1`.  On the next pass, you do the same thing.

Comment: You code cannot work.  If your table contains zero rows then dt.Rows.Count = 0. So i = 0 is not less than zero so you never enter the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop ends when you've added dt.Rows.Count - but your loop is adding rows, so it never ends.